# Can a Struct Named "AB" Contain an Array of AB?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
typedef struct unit
{
struct unit * next;

int year;
int month;
int day;
struct unit revisions[3];
char subject[100];
}schedule;
```

The above code is giving me the following error:

```
array type has incomplete element type
 struct unit revisions[3];
```

I'm guessing the problem is that a struct cannot contain an array of itself? If so, how can I achieve similar functionality?

Comment: No, a struct cannot contain an array of itself (how would that be possible?) But you can always use a pointer instead.

Comment: It is not possible to embed definition has not been completed. Set the area it later using the pointer as an alternative.

Comment: No, it would need infinite memory! `sizeof(struct unit) = 3*sizeof(struct unit) + x`

Comment: BTW: If you introduce a struct-tag and a typedef-name for the same type, consider using the same token for both. That reduces useless cognitive load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good workaround:

```
typedef struct unit{
    struct unit * next;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    struct unit *revisions; //just like you do with struct unit *next
    char subject[100];
}schedule;

schedule s;
s.revisions = malloc(3 * sizeof *s.revisions);
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). Also look how you can use `sizeof` in a less error-prone way.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh my! I'm learning some good practices each day! How would I use `sizeof` "in a less error-prone way" though? would it be something like `malloc(3 * sizeof s.revisions)`?

Comment: Thanks, I'd gone ahead and did something similar on my own. Hopefully this will help other newbies xD

Answer (score 4):

your question contains the answer itself. `struct unit * next;`

You can always use a pointer to the structure type inside the structure definition, and from your function, allocate memory and use it.